# Forwarding signed transactions as if they were sent by key owners

Tags: proxy-contracts, sendsignedtransaction

Can a contract act as a postal worker for a human user / key owner? The idea is the key owner would sign two transactions. The first transaction is for any call to any address. The second transaction is to the forwarding contract and this second transaction contains the first transaction. Can the forwarding contract execute the first transaction on chain as if the key owner has executed it on their own?